# Anchor link speed even on every part of page

Tags: javascript, html

I created/used this code for anchor scrolling:

```
$('#Anchors').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = this.hash;
  var $target = $(target);
  var scrollTo = $target.offset().top - 80
  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: scrollTo+'px'}, 1200);
});
```

I need help because if i am on top of the page and press link to scroll down on page it's too fast. But if i am on half page and press anchor then speed will be ok. So how can I make speed of scrolling same on every part of page?

Comment: add some math. scrollTo / total_page_height * 1200 (for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a natural behavior because the duration (1200ms) is fixed and it has to be faster for longer distances.
but if you want to solve this by javascript you can make the duration dynamic:

```
  $('#Anchors').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);
    var scrollTo = $target.offset().top;

    var distance = Math.abs($(window).scrollTop() - scrollTo)
    var duration = distance/750; // 750px in 1s, you can change it
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: scrollTo+'px'}, duration * 1000, 'linear');
  });
```

This guarantees that **speed** is almost (or certainly, if easing was 'linear') is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This simple smoothscroll in your css could be useful.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```